# npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok while installing modules with gulp

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install, node-gyp

I have a package.json with these dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "core-js": "^3.4.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
  }
}
```

and my node and npm are the newest.
But when I run npm install there are errors like:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
 installation...
npm ERR! Please restart this script from an administrative PowerShell!
npm ERR! The build tools cannot be installed without administrative rights.
npm ERR! To fix, right-click on PowerShell and run "as Administrator".


npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post your node verion? and you enviroment? (like OS etc) do you have python installed? ifnyes wich version ?

Comment: Did you try to run PowerShell as administrator?